# digiKam cannot find photos after upgrading to a larger hard drive [Linux] [Ubuntu 22.04]

Tags: troubleshooting, photo-management, digikam, digital-asset-management

I'm using digiKam 7.5 on an Ubuntu 22.04 system.

After upgrading my laptop's SSD to a larger one (to make more room for more photos of course :) ) by backing up my home directory and then restoring it on the new drive digiKam thinks the drive containing the album has disappeared, in spite of them being at exactly the same path, since the volume's UUID changed.

How can I convince digiKam that my photos are, in fact, still where I left them?

Answer (score 1):

I found an [old mail thread from 2011](https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/digikam-users/2011-October/014709.html) and some bugs ([267131](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=267131), [456749](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=456749)) that discuss a similar issue. It also seemed to suggest how the digiKam database could be updated to fix the issue.

It seems that, even for non-removable drives, digiKam considers the volume's UUID to be part of the file path to the album. A new filesystem created on a new drive will have a differnt UUID even though it contains the same data as the old. For each root album digiKam stores, in its sql database, a record like:

```
.headers on
select * from AlbumRoots limit 10;
id|label|status|type|identifier|specificPath
1|digikam|0|1|volumeid:?uuid=90ee45ae-cd07-4e23-a948-7ddf8afff45f|/home/brick/Pictures/digikam
```

It combines the volume UUID from the `identifier` column with the path in the `specificPath` column to decide where to look for files. If it does not find a volume with the specified UUID it considers the album to be missing.

Summarily, fixing it involves:

1. Use the `blkid` command to find the UUID of your new volume
2. Use the `sqlite3` command to open digiKam's database
3. Update the offending `AlbumRoot` record to the new disk's UUID.
4. Alternatively, change the `AlbumRoot` to a UUID-free rubric. Should avoid similar issues going forward, but also seemed to be necessary if using a ZFS based filesystem since digiKam does not seem to pick up the UUID.

#### 1. Getting the new UUID

On my system `blkid` gave:

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda4: LABEL="rpool" UUID="8788856976958701461" UUID_SUB="2923538069334769741" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="24ffc0e5-7b57-9940-8526-e267bf4e194a"
/dev/sda2: UUID="a59d3973-47b8-42ec-9d64-755553a7bb33" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4a88d048-d33e-0142-bed0-14bc7d1a5e34"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="bpool" UUID="11746124927107044680" UUID_SUB="12202475822180589330" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="252ae807-f008-d54a-a63d-3b9df9dfff1e"
/dev/sda1: UUID="DB82-0239" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="dbb46316-3caf-4f7b-b26c-dde89c848141"
```

I moved to using a ZFS root directory, so the `/dev/sda4: LABEL="rpool" ...` entry's `PARTUUID="24ffc0e5-7b57-9940-8526-e267bf4e194a"` section gives me the required UUID.

#### 2. Open the digiKam database

First ensure you have sqlite3 installed by running, in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install sqlite3
```

You need to find the file named `digikam4.db`. Where this file lives will be up to how you installed digiKam. TBH I'm not exactly sure how to easily and reliably find this file, but I knew mine was stored in the same directory as my first album.

Before you go further, quit digiKam (make sure you got all the windows) and make a backup of the database file in case you break it with the updates. In my case, in a terminal:

```
cp /home/brick/Pictures/digikam/digikam4.db cp /home/brick/Pictures/digikam/digikam4.db.backup
```

Then open the database file with `sqlite3` in a terminal:

```
sqlite3 /home/brick/Pictures/digikam/digikam4.db
```

#### 3. Fix the UUID using sqlite3

Find the current (problematic) AlbumRoot (the `.headers` line is optional but makes it easier to see what is going on) by typing in the `sqlite3` terminal session:

```
.headers on
select * from AlbumRoots limit 10;
```

In my case this returned a single record:

```
id|label|status|type|identifier|specificPath
1|digikam|0|1|volumeid:?uuid=90ee45ae-cd07-4e23-a948-7ddf8afff45f|/home/brick/Pictures/digikam
```

Now we replace the UUID by the one we found in step 1 using `blkid`, in my case `24ffc0e5-7b57-9940-8526-e267bf4e194a` in the `sqlite3` terminal session:

```
update AlbumRoots set identifier = 'volumeid:?uuid=24ffc0e5-7b57-9940-8526-e267bf4e194a' where identifier = 'volumeid:?uuid=90ee45ae-cd07-4e23-a948-7ddf8afff45f';
```

I added the `where` clause just from the habit of never doing unqualified SQL `update` statements. If you had multiple album roots this would prevent you from breaking other records that were correct.

So, templated the update would be

```
update AlbumRoots set identifier = 'volumeid:?uuid=<OLD UUID>' where identifier = 'volumeid:?uuid=<NEW UUID>'
```

Now you should be done. Start up digiKam and, hopefully, everything is as it should be.

##### 4. Alternative ending to 3. without using UUID

I had updated my filesystem from `ext4` to `ZFS` and, even when I made this fix, digiKam still did not recognize my album. With a bit of experimentation (adding another album) it seems that digiKam does not recognise the UUID of my ZFS partition and, instead, created an `AlbumRoot` entry in a UUID-free format. I then converted my main album to the same format by doing, in the `sqlite3` terminal session:

```
update AlbumRoots set identifier = 'volumeid:?path=/home/brick/Pictures/digikam' where specificPath = '/home/brick/Pictures/digikam';
update AlbumRoots set specificPath = '/' where specificPath = '/home/brick/Pictures/digikam';
```

Afterwards the `AlbumRoots` table looked like this:

```
sqlite> select * from AlbumRoots limit 10;
id|label|status|type|identifier|specificPath
1|digikam|0|1|volumeid:?path=/home/brick/Pictures/digikam|/
```

In summary, the `identifier` column becomes `volumeid:?path=<absolute_path_to_your_album>` and the `specificPath` column simply becomes `/`.

Q: Why do it this way?
A: You won't run into a similar issue if you upgrade your drive again, as long as you always store the same album in the same absolute path. If you are using ZFS it seems you have no choice.

Q: Why *not* do it this way?
A: For albums on removable drives digiKam won't be able to disambiguate between different physical drives that happen to be mounted at the same, temporary, mount point. For Albums on your fixed / internal drive it should be absolutely fine though.